# Show button if two values are equal

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm finishing up an app of mine, which is a forum, and I need users to be able to delete their own topics.

So, In my "Topics List" template, I have successfully rendered the following code:

```
<body ng-app>
[...]
<button ng-show="estudante == 'admin'"></button>
[...]
```

From:

```
<button ng-show="{{ request.user.username }}=='{{ topic.creator }}'">Remover Tópico</button>
```

This button should not be displayed if the values of topic.creator and request.user.username are not equal. However, ng-if, ng-hide and ng-show properly configured don't seem to have any effect.

Is there a way to get this to work? Am I missing something on the scopes topic? :)

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Using '' in both values or none is the same. The button is displayed if the value mismatches:

[Forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccfS7.png)

Comment: I think it's getting `estudante` as a variable, not as a value, you could try rendering `'estudante'`

Comment: Have you tried without the string quotes (or with quotes on both values)?

Comment: Hello guys, thank you the the replies. Yes, the behavior of the app is the same no matter how quotes are setup (see UPDATE screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you dont need the curly brackets around the variable like {{xxx}} in this case. And also the '' can be removed, maybe it works after removing them.

```
<button ng-show="request.user.username == topic.creator">Remover Tópico</button>
```

Comment: Hi Terajoel, thank you for your reply!

Unfortunately, removing the brackets renders the template unable to fetch the desired values. The code is shown as simple text ----->

<button ng-show="request.user.username==topic.creator">Remover Tópico</button> -----

Comment: @FernandoWessek Yes but it shouldn't be a problem that it renders it like text, angular should be able to handle this. Did you make a test and try once with both not equal and once both equal? it should work.

Comment: @FernandoWessek On other pages it is also done like this and it seems to work: https://postimg.org/image/lb3pqvvkn/

Comment: Yes, both tests failed. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ng-show="reqeust.user.role === 'admin' && user.username === topic.crator">Remover Tópico</button>
```

i think this solve this problemn, but verify your code.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thank you for your reply!

That doesn't work. If I don't use brackets in "ng-show" the HTML result doesn't get the proper usernames. I have tried my code with three equal signs, and without "request." as you mentioned, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button ng-show="request.user.username == topic.creator">Remover Tópico</button>
```

In your controller you should have the values you wish to compare assigned to $scope something like this:

```
$scope.request.user.username = "some name";
$scope.topic.creator = "some name";
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something related to scopes! Will update the solution found based on what you posted. THANKS!!

Comment: Accepting a correct answer would help the community! Thanks